# Delete a image album from SD card using MediaStore

Tags: android

Given I'm writing a App which allows a user to move Albums from the SD card into the local storage, then I have a `delete` function on the `ExternalAlbum` class like this:

```
public void delete(ContentResolver resolver) {
    resolver.delete(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(mBucketId)});
}
```

This deletes all files within that specific folder. Say `/mnt/sdcard2/Pictures/MyAlbum` will be empty after calling this.

What is the best method to delete the folder as well? I have the ID of the content bucket already, this could be re-used.

**In other words:** I'm looking for the MediaStore API to delete the Bucket itself, not just the files within the bucket.

Comment: use `MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID` instead of `BUCKET_ID`. `BUCKET_ID` belongs to the folder id

Comment: @PankajKumar but wouldn't that be the ID of the album? As said, the delete method above belongs to a Album class.

Comment: Yes correct. You should use both ids to delete a particular image

Comment: @PankajKumar - this is not what I'm looking for, sorry. I need to delete the album, the folder, using the MediaStore API.

Comment: ok no problem. My comment was for your first asked question not for edited one. :)

Comment: @PankajKumar - oh perhaps I should write it more clear. Before & after edit should communicate the same issue.